# Issue in disabling Jdatechooser

Tags: java, swing

I am using JDateChooser from jcalendar-1.4.jar.

```
maturityDateChooser = new JDateChooser();
 maturityDateChooser.setEnabled(false);
```

this is not disabling my datechooser component. Am I missing something?

Below is the setEnabled code of JDateChooser

```
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (dateEditor != null) {
            dateEditor.setEnabled(enabled);
            calendarButton.setEnabled(enabled);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works fine for me, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

can try like this:

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.getDateEditor().setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I am getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser.getDateEditor()Lcom/toedter/calendar/IDateEditor;

Comment: It should be there, [public IDateEditor getDateEditor() {
  return dateEditor;
 }] (https://github.com/inqwell/jcalendar/blob/master/src/main/java/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.java#L489)

Comment: public void setEnabled(boolean enabled); (https://github.com/inqwell/jcalendar/blob/master/src/main/java/com/toedter/calendar/IDateEditor.java#L138)

Comment: This api is not present in jcalendar-1.2.2 jar

Comment: On the top of question you wrote, you are using jcalendar-1.4.jar.